# How can I create an animated device mockup?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, animation, gif

Say I have a GIF such as this:

[image]

How could I create something like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/1210899-Compose-iOS-7), where the user added this video into a still shot of an iPhone?

Better yet, if I could put it in a mockup like [this](http://dribbble.com/shots/750626-iPhone-5-Mock-ups-FREEMIUM?list=searches&tag=iphone_5_template) where it has a smart layer that I would normally just drop my still image into, but in this case I'd love a GIF. I have Adobe Photoshop CS6.

Comment: According to the discussion on the Dribbble file you linked to: After Effects

Comment: nice find @DA01

Comment: Mocha will also do this. Lotsa plug-ins. Awesome control.

Answer (score 1):

CreativeDash used [this template](http://ui8.net/showcase-template) to make that animation effect (It's $14 but there's a free preview).  Hope that helps!

P.S. Make sure you have After Effects and Photoshop installed!

Answer (score 0):

Prepare every stage in a layer. Open window -> animation from photoshop menu, click the small icon which located top left of animation panel then choose "make frames from layers", set the time from bottom left of animation panel and save for web as gif.

Answer (score 0):

You can use photoshop by creating different different layers for different key frames and using timeline option in photoshop you can generate gif animations.

Answer (score 0):

**THE MOST SIMPLE WAY:** THIS IS A FREE ANIMATED MOCKUP .PSD FILE of a website scroll dow and a menu animation completely edit and animated in photoshop ridiculous easy to edit and play around, you can download the file for free [here](http://freegoodiesfordesigners.blogspot.se/2014/07/free-photoshop-animated-menu-for-mobile.html), i also have a tutorial video of how is easy to edit this freebie.
[image]