# Mobile UI Animation

Tags: animation, interface-design, gif

can anybody tell how do they animate the mobile UI/design to showcase their work.I have used Photoshop but the GIF quality sucks, i wonder what would be the best way to get the desire result please see the link for example. Thanks

[Gif Animation](http://www.pinterest.com/pin/72479875227673252/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an animated device mockup](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/20725/how-can-i-create-an-animated-device-mockup) and [How to create animated GIFs of prototype mockups, like the ones on Dribbble?](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble)

Comment: Yes :) did you get the answer?

Comment: Well I got an up vote for my answer in the second question I linked, if that is what you mean.

Comment: yep ! i will use After effects

Comment: If you are using [this answer](http://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/31207/how-to-create-animated-gifs-of-prototype-mockups-like-the-ones-on-dribbble/31302#31302) to help you out. Comment in it if you feel it's missing something.